# Save Default Image if none selected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf

I have a following situation:

The Image control to show the image and a button to open file dialog to choose it. Later that image would be saved to the database. But if user don't select any image how can I show a default image and save it in same way as if it was selected?

```
byte[] dtImagem = null;

private void btnAddImg(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog _fd = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (_fd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            _fs = new FileStream(_fd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            dtImagem = new byte[_fs.Length];
            _fs.Read(dadosImagem, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(_fs.Length));
            _fs.Close();

            ImageSourceConverter imgs = new ImageSourceConverter();
            imgPessoa.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, imgs.ConvertFromString(_fd.FileName.ToString()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro :: " + ex.Message);
        }                          
    }
    else
    {
        //Here is the problem how can i use dtImage and save it on database?
        var uri = new Uri(@"/AppWPF;component/Images/images.png");
        ImageSourceConverter imgs = new ImageSourceConverter();
        imgPessoa.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty,imgs.ConvertFromString(uri.ToString()));
    }
}
```

My code for insertion to the database works, I just need a way to add a default image if user selects none

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is better to initialize the image with default value from the beginning and show that image to the users so they are aware of what is going to be saved. And you can initialize your `dtImagem` at the same time. That way you dont need your `else` in `btnAddImg`, maybe only additional button to reset the image to the default one...  But that's up to you :)

To answer your question - how to get bytes array from the resource the answer is:

```
var info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    info.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    dtImagem = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```